# Let $X_1, X_2$ be standard normal, Show $Y_1,Y_2$ are either independent or not independent.

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are standard normal. So they each have pdf's $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x_1^2}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x_2^2}{2}$

Define $Y_1 = X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2 = (X_1 - X_2)^2$. Prove or disprove that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.

So that would be showing $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y_1)\mathbb{P}(Y_2  = y_2)$.

I know that $Y_1$ will be Normal$(0,2)$ , I think $Y_2$ will also have a normal distribution.

My problem here is that won't $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y_2) = 0$ and similarly for $Y_2$ so I am not sure how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: $P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2)=P(Y_1=y_1)P(Y_2=y_2)$ does not guarantee independence. It is true in lots of cases. Even if $Y_1=Y_2$ and $Y_1$ has continuous distribution ($0=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- If $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a joint normal distribution then $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ also have a joint normal distribution.
- If $U$ and $V$ have a joint normal distribution then they are independent if they are uncorrelated.
- If $U$ and $V$ are independent then for suitable functions $f,g$ also $f(U)$ and $g(V)$ are independent. This can be used to prove that $U$ and $V^2$ are independent.

Comment: If I am correct both $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1 - X_2$ are Normal$(0,2)$. Then I want to use covariance. Both above have mean $0$. So I need to calculate       $  \mathbb{E}((X_1+X_2)((X_1 - X_2))$ Which is $\mathbb{E}(X^2_1 + X^2_2 = \mathbb{E}(X_1^2) + \mathbb{E}(X_2^2) = Var(X_1)+(\mathbb{E}(X_1)^2 + Var(X_2) + (\mathbb{E}(X_2)^2 = 2$. So Covariance isn't $0$ so they aren't uncorrelated. I thought uncorrelated doesn't imply independence?

Comment: To continue, if I take $f(U) = U$ and $g(V) = V^2$ the above shows they won't be independent since independence fails in the above comment.

Comment: $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)=\mathbb E(X_1+X_2)(X_1-X_2)=\mathbb E(X_1^2-X_2^2)=\mathbb EX_1^2-\mathbb EX_2^2=1-1=0$

Comment: Oh I duh, I had the wrong sign. To complete the solution would I then calculate the covariance of $(X_1+X+2, (X_1-X_2)^2)$ or is the above sufficient enough to declare the independence?

Comment: The above is enough if you combine it with what is mentioned under the third bullet.